# cakephp mysql ,autoincrement id or varchar as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I am building a web application with cakephp 2.4 and I have firstly designed my users table with an integer auto-incrementing id, than since my urls are structured as : `http://mywebsite/users/view/username`  I realized that instead of using an integer auto-increment, it may be better for performance to use username(VARCHAR 100) as my primary key.Now I am curious how would this approach affect site performance when the database grows.

Comment: You can use url-rewrite for user friendly urls but integer id is better than what you are suggesting here ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per other answers, use an integer for your PK. Pick the correct int size depending on how many records you're expecting. Not using an integer PK with Cake might cause some problems. if you're using a Framework, stick with it's conventions - that's the advantage of a framework!

DO NOT generate a unique route for every user dynamically in your routes.php. That goes against the entire point of having generic routing. One route should account for this, and you deal with it in the relevant controller.

For example, if you specify all of your real controllers/actions:

```
Router::connect('/:controller', array('controller' => 'user|anotherController|etc'));
Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'something'), array('action' => 'allowed|actions|etc'));
Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'else'), array('action' => 'allowed|actions|etc'));
```

You can then send everything else, as in, site.com/username, to somewhere specific.

```
Router::connect('/:username', array('controller' => 'users'), array('action' => 'view'), array('pass'=>array('username'), 'username' => 'regex'));
```

And accept the 'username' var in the view function, and use that to find the correct user from your db. Also, note that if

Answer (score 1):

Don't use varchars as your primary key.  It's horrible for performance, you need to explicitly check that you don't have duplicate keys, it's not conventional, foreign keys then need to be varchar, the router won't handle it properly... ugh.

If you're worried about SEO, then you can read up on how [the cakePHP router can handle this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

In my application I dynamically generate a routes file with the seo url that is matched to the ID of the thing that I'm trying to display.  In your case this file would have entries like:

```
Router::connect('/users/view/johndoe', array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'view',
            13));
```

This solution works very well for me, and the seo portions are handled by an SEO behavior that is attached to the model.  It also works with reverse routing, so that when you make a link like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $user['User']['id'])); ?>
```

it will automatically create a link like /users/view/johndoe.  If you decide to change this structure later on, or have a special user with a special path (like http://mywebsite.com/user-john-connor) then this will automatically change all links to that user's view to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to create **varchar2** as primary key, I think it's better to be as int with auto-incremental and you can use routeing in cakephp  : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

to be : http://yourwebsite.com/:username

good luck